# Grabbing other element's from array firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am needing help with grabbing certain details about an audio uploaded to my Firestore Database. This is how the data is entered in my document for the audio : [image: Firestore]

It can take in multiple audio urls with information and store them in the array of AudioUrl. I originally had it to where it just took in the audio url with no additional information except the name but it was structured like this `wowza:"https://firbase......"` and would be able to fetch the key as the audio name and the value as the audio file. Ever since I have changed the structure of the data to allow additonal information for each audio url uploaded, I have been having a hard time figuring out to actually fetch the rest of the data. This is my current api call to grab the data from firestore:

```
            guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else { return }
        for document in documents {
            let songID = document.documentID
            let data = document.data()
            let uid = data["uid"] as! String
            let photoURL = data["photoURL"] as? String
            let trackTitle = data["trackTitle"] as? String
            let url = URL (string:photoURL!)
            let coverImageURL = data["coverImage"] as? String
            let imageURL = URL (string:coverImageURL!)
            let audios = data["AudioUrl"] as! [[String:Any]]
            var audioNames  = [String]()
            var audioUrls  = [URL]()
            let timestamp = data["timestampt"] as? Double
            for audio in audios{
                let audioName = audio.first?.key
                let audioUrl = audio.first?.value as? String
                let songURL = URL (string:audioUrl!)
                audioNames.append(audioName!)
                audioUrls.append(songURL!)
                UserService.shared.fetchUser(uid: uid) { user in
                  let song = SongPost(id: songID, author: user, title: trackTitle!, coverImage: imageURL!, audioUrl: audioUrls , audioName: audioNames , likes: 0 , timestamp: timestamp!, streams: 0)
                  self.songs.removeAll(where: {$0.id == songID})
                  self.songs.append(song)
                  self.songs = self.songs.sorted(by: { $0.createdAt > $1.createdAt})
                  self.collectionView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
```

The for loop where it starts as `for audio in audios` is where I fetch the information about the audio url stored in the array. I'm sure there is a way to splice the array or grab each element by index but I am sadly stuck on this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: So `AudioUrl` is an array of maps, correct? Each entry in this array is a map with three keys (`File`, `Likes`, `Name`) and you want to iterate over a snapshot of documents and get these three values, correct?

Comment: @liquid yes that is correct!

Answer (score 0):

The Firestore syntax is straightforward:

```
for doc in documents {
    if let audioUrl = doc.get("audioUrl") as? [[String: Any]] {
        for url in audioURL {
            if let name = url["Name"] as? String {
                print(name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This would be a good time to mess around in an Xcode playground. `AudioURL` is an array of dictionaries (called maps in Firestore) so just create an arbitrary array of dictionaries and get the hang of them. Plug this into a playground:

```
import Foundation

let audioURL: [[String: Any]] = [
    ["File": "abc123", "Likes": 0, "Name": "Wowza"],
    ["File": "xyz456", "Likes": 1, "Name": "Yowza"]
]

for url in audioURL {
    if let file = url["File"] as? String,
       let likes = url["Likes"] as? Int,
       let name = url["Name"] as? String {
        print(file, likes, name)
    }
}
```